# how to organize cmd's arguments that are supposed to be on multiple lines?

Tags: python, subprocess

The program being called requires arguments being supplied on multiple lines, e.g.

```
some_program par0_1 par0_2 << EOF > out.log
par1_1 par1_2 par1_3 par1_4 
par2_1 par2_2 
par3_1 par3_2 par3_3 
par4_1
quit
EOF
```

So far I have only had success with `shell=True` (subprocess.Popen(), subprocess.call(), os.system(), etc etc are all okay with this). What I did was to write a "parameters" file and organize things into

> 'cmd < parameters >> log 2>&1'

and let shell to interpret it. For example:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'some_program'
settings = 'par0_1 par0_2'
cmd += settings
arg = ['par1_1 par1_2 par1_3 par1_4', 
       'par2_1 par2_2', 
       'par3_1 par3_2 par3_3', 
       'par4_1', 
       'quit']
with open('parameters', 'wt') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(arg))
cmd += ' < parameters >> out.log 2>&1'
subprocess.call('cmd', shell=True)
```

But I really want to know how to do this with `shell=False`. Tried many things but as long as I organize things into a list it was problematic. Using `subprocess.communicate()` to supply similar parameters to `stdin` might work (would be chunky though). But I really appreciate if someone has a simpler and more elegant solution - many programs written in Fortran ask for arguments like this and I hope people already have a `shell=False` solution handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct you are currently using in your shell is known as a [Here Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells), and simply results in the data being feed to the process by bash on *stdin*.

It can be easily replicated using [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) in the following way:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

# here is the command and arguments, along with data for stdin
cmd = ['some_program', 'arg_0', 'arg_1']
lines = ['par1_1 par1_2 par1_3 par1_4',
         'par2_1 par2_2',
         'par3_1 par3_2 par3_3',
         'par4_1',
         'quit']

# create the process - in this example redirect stderr to stdout
process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

# feed it the lines on stdin and get back the contents of stdout and stderr
stdout, stderr = process.communicate('\n'.join(lines))
print stdout
```

For example:

```
>>> process = Popen(["cat"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> stdout, stderr = process.communicate('\n'.join(['hello there', 'VXtal']))
>>> print stdout
hello there
VXtal
```

Comment: hello there, @donkopotamus! yup that worked. so I indeed need to feed the multiple lines to stdin through a pipe (no params file needed, that's neat). nice to let python to handle all the stdin, stdout, and stderr, needing no shell - otherwise may just write a simple sh script... thanks dude!